# $.getScript() fails inside self-invoking function

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am trying to run `$.getScript()` inside a self-invoking function, but I can't get it to work.

**The initial working code:**

```
        function loadScript(){


                    $.getScript("script.js")
                    .done(function(){
                        console.log("[INFO] Script was imported!")
                    })
                    .fail(function(){
                        console.error("[ERROR] Couldn't import Script!")
                    })

        }

loadScript()
```

**The not-working code (after I put it inside a self-invoking function)**

```
(function(){
        function loadScript(){


                    $.getScript("script.js")
                    .done(function(){
                        console.log("[INFO] Script was imported!")
                    })
                    .fail(function(){
                        console.error("[ERROR] Couldn't import Script!")
                    })

        }

        loadScript()
})();
```

How can I get this to work? **It returns me the fail function**.

EDIT: I tried to remove the docsready but it still returns the `fail` function while executing the `$.getScript`

Comment: You're not calling `loadScript` in the 2nd example. You don't want a IIFE there either. You just need a closure assuming you just want to create a private environment to keep your variables from escaping.

Comment: How come you are calling the `$.getScript` in another function inside the docready? Can't you just call the `$.getScript` inside the docready?

Comment: So it is not because of the self invoking function but because your `$.getScript` fails.

Comment: Given your edit, if the first one works, the second one will as well. But I'm happy to be taught differently with a JSFiddle demo.

Comment: @FelixKling I tried to remove the docsready, but still the `$.getScript` returns the fail function.

Comment: That makes for a new question.